# jQuery scan through div class name, use those class names to print matching checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm very new to javascript/jquery and was wondering if it were at all possible to collect a div's class names and then create checkboxes based on those class names with jQuery. For example.

```
<div class="champ">
  <h3>Reading</h3>
</div>

<div class="league1">
  <h3>Sheffield Wednesday</h3>
</div>

<div class="prem">
  <h3>Sunderland</h3>
</div>

<div class="prem">
  <h3>Tottenham Hotspur</h3>
</div>

<div class="champ">
  <h3>Watford</h3>
</div>
```

Say that is my html file with the associated class names, I would essentially like the result to spit out checkboxes with the class names present for the divs while avoiding any duplication of the same class name.

So for the example above it would end up looking like

- champ
- league1
- prem

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Should they be checked, or unchecked, by default? What if there's more than two class-names in an element?

Comment: Unchecked by default, I'm aiming to try sort through soccer teams by league. Not quite sure about the two class names as I haven't really thought that far.

Comment: Really too strict to close this question. The question is pretty clear, and also is the reason for the question : "**I'm very new to javascript/jquery and was wondering if**" ...Is there a closing-contest going on?

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally suggest:

```
// creating new elements:
var newCheckbox = $('<input />', {
    'type' : 'checkbox',
    'name' : 'UKFootballClubs'
}),
    newLabel = $('<label />');
    wrapper = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
// iterating over each div that has a class:
$('div[class]').each(function(){
    /* appending a cloned label element, with the text set to the class-name
       of the current div element: */
    newLabel.clone().text(this.className).appendTo(wrapper);
    /* appending a clone of the new checkbox to the new label, 
       this allows a click on the label to un/select the checkbox: */
    newCheckbox.clone().prependTo(wrapper.find('label').last());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/as2Uj/).

A slightly altered version that uses the team-names (from the `div`) as the `label`-text in order to avoid having two check-boxes with the `prem` text:

```
var newCheckbox = $('<input />', {
    'type' : 'checkbox',
    'name' : 'UKFootballClubs'
}),
    newLabel = $('<label />');
    wrapper = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
$('div[class]').each(function(){
    newLabel.clone().text($(this).text()).appendTo(wrapper);
    newCheckbox.clone().prependTo(wrapper.find('label').last());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/as2Uj/1/).

However, if you would rather use the class-names ('prem', 'champ', etc) then you can prevent duplicate checkbox-text by checking for the existence of an element which contains that text before appending a new element with that text:

```
var newCheckbox = $('<input />', {
    'type' : 'checkbox',
    'name' : 'UKFootballClubs'
}),
    newLabel = $('<label />');
    wrapper = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
$('div[class]').each(function(){
    var text = $.trim(this.className);
    if (!wrapper.find('label:contains('+text+')').length) {
        newLabel.clone().text(text).appendTo(wrapper);
        newCheckbox.clone().prependTo(wrapper.find('label').last());
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/as2Uj/4/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).
- [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: This one duplicates the class names.  The OP seemed to want only one checkbox for "champ" and one for "prem".

Comment: You're absolutely right, which is precisely why I posted the second code block; unfortunately, without clear guidance from the OP I'm unsure of precisely what he wants, and while I'm happy to help in the absence of clarity, I don't have the time to cater to all possible inferences.

Comment: Self-administered dope-slap!  I read the code up to the link, saw the fiddle and added the comment.  I'm pretty sure, though, that what's wanted is three check-boxes, "champ", "league1", and "prem", one for each class that occurs.

Comment: No problem, I've updated the answer to address that problem, should it be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

A **very** *simple* / *illustrative* way to do it :

```
$('div').each(function(i,e) {
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    var input='<input type="checkbox">'+className;
    $('body').append(input).append('<br>');
});
```

outputs :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.each to loop through each div. and have the function parameter create a dynamic checkbox element with a class that matches the current divs class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you!

```
var names = [];
$('div').map(function() {
    return this.name;
}).each(function(i, str) {
    if (!~$.inArray(str, names)) 
    names.push(str);
});
```

Comment: This filters the duplicates, but doesn't actually create the checkboxes as requested.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rgin/E7xZa/

```
$('div').each( function() {
    x = $(this).prop('class');
    $('<input />', { type:'checkbox', id:x,  name: x}).appendTo( $('.checklist') );
    $('<label />', { for:x, text:x }).appendTo( $('.checklist') );
});
```

This should work for you. Of course, you'll want to use a better variable than just `x`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var myArray= new Array();
    window.onload = function(){


        var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        var k=0;
        for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
        {
            var classes= ele[i].getAttribute('class');
            if(!there(classes))
            {
                myArray[k] = classes;
                k++;
            }           
        }
        var data="";
        for(var j=0;j<myArray.length;j++)
        {
            data += '<input type="checkbox" name="group" value="'+myArray[j]+'">'+myArray[j];
        }

            // Or do whatever you want
        document.write(data);
    }

function there(classes)
{
    for(var j=0;j<myArray.length;j++)
    {
        if(myArray[j]==classes)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to replace `there` with **[Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** > -1?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var uniqClass = [];
    $('div').each(function(){
        var className = $(this).attr('class');       
        if(!uniqClass[className]){
            uniqClass[className] = className;
        }
    });

    for(var prop in uniqClass){
        var input='<input type="checkbox">'+uniqClass[prop];
        $('body').append(input).append('<br>');
    }
})
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vBhng/

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the answers seem to be missing the grouping of class names.  Here's **[a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/eJthn/)** that does it, using some functional programming techniques (`reduce`, `map`):

```
var $checkboxes = $("<p>" + Object.keys($('div').toArray().map(function(div) {
    return div.className;
}).reduce(function(acc, name) {
    acc[name] = 1; return acc;
}, {})).reduce(function(html, name) {
    return html + name + ": " + "<input type='checkbox' id='cb-" + name + "' checked>"; 
}, "") + "<" + "/p>");
$checkboxes.appendTo("body");
```

If you don't have `reduce`, `map`, or `Object.keys` in all your target environments, MDN has shims for them on the respective pages.

The Fiddle also includes some behavior for the checkboxes, hiding the related `DIV`s if the checkboxes were unchecked.  I have no idea of the overall goal of the OP, but this was just to demonstrate one way to keep the checkbox connected to the class name that generated it, by making it part of the name of the checkbox:

```
$checkboxes.on("change", ":checkbox",  function(evt) {
    var cb = this, className = cb.id.substring(3);
    $("." + className)[cb.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();
});
```

But this might or might not be important to the main goal.